# Is it possible to get rid of these loops?

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements, python-imaging-library

Here are the two loops:

```
value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(10):
    if m[i] < max_iter:
        value[i] = 255

for i in range(10):
   draw.point((x[i], y), (hue[i], sat[i], value[i]))
```

These are two different problems, but might as well ask for both.
So for the first one: Is it possible to set the values with the condition directly in a list (or tuple)?
And for the second one: Is it possible to draw multiple points at once with the pillow module? I originally planned on putting all 10 points to be simultaneously drawn as a list as the first variable, which works, but I have problems to set their color value separately.

Comment: for the first problem: `value = [255 if m[i] < max_iter else 0 for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one works as a comprehension, but is harder to understand for beginners.

```
value = [255 if m[i] < max_iter else 0 for i in range(10)]
```

For drawing points the loop makes the most sense.

Comment: Well that's certainly more tidy, thanks. Do you by any chance know what would be faster (with a loop or setting every variable individually)?

Comment: @Ein_grünes_Beb to answer the question what's faster: A comprehension is a little bit faster, but in general: There's the `timeit`module in Python so whenever you ask yourself if something is faster: Just measure it yourself... (https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)